# UnityWebRequest change to https

Tags: unity-game-engine, ssl

I had working infrastructure of unity android app and site api working under `http`.

Recently I have switched the server and applied `ssl certificate`. Now my api is under `https`.

In unity app I'm using `UnityWebRequest` to communicate with my api. The logical change after switching to `https` will be changing all api addressees within the app from `http` to `https`. I did this, but my api is behaving weirdly. (Giving my own error status as a response all the time, whereas giving good response on old server without certificate.)

Is there anything extra I need to change with the switch to `https`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually Unity would handle the certificate automatically and validate it against known root certificates or ignore them completely depending on the platform:

> **[UnityWebRequest.certificateHandler:](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-certificateHandler.html)**
>  Setting this property to `null` makes the platform use the default certificate validation. Some platforms will validate certificates against a root certificate authority store. Other platforms will simply bypass certificate validation completely.

Using a **self-signed** certificate, however, will fail if Unity decides for the first.

---

So, for `https` with a self-signed certificate you might have to implement a [`CertificateHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.CertificateHandler.ValidateCertificate.html) that implements the method `ValidateCertificate`.

You could either simply bypass the certificate by accepting them **all** (which is easier but ofcourse would make the `https` kind of pointless)

```c#
public class BypassCertificate : CertificateHandler
{
    protected override bool ValidateCertificate(byte[] certificateData)
    {
        //Simply return true no matter what
        return true;
    }
}
```

Or try this example from the docs with your public key

```c#
// Based on https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning#.Net
class AcceptAllCertificatesSignedWithASpecificPublicKey : CertificateHandler
{
    // Encoded RSAPublicKey
    private static string PUB_KEY = "30818902818100C4A06B7B52F8D17DC1CCB47362" +
        "C64AB799AAE19E245A7559E9CEEC7D8AA4DF07CB0B21FDFD763C63A313A668FE9D764E" +
        "D913C51A676788DB62AF624F422C2F112C1316922AA5D37823CD9F43D1FC54513D14B2" +
        "9E36991F08A042C42EAAEEE5FE8E2CB10167174A359CEBF6FACC2C9CA933AD403137EE" +
        "2C3F4CBED9460129C72B0203010001";

    protected override bool ValidateCertificate(byte[] certificateData)
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateData);

        string pk = certificate.GetPublicKeyString();

        return pk.Equals(PUB_KEY));
    }
}
```

And add it to your request

```c#
using(var www = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://example.com"))
{
    //www.certificateHandler = new BypassCertificate();
    // Or
    www.certificateHandler = new AcceptAllCertificatesSignedWithASpecificPublicKey();

    yield return www.SendWebRequest();
    
    //...
}
```

> Note: Custom certificate validation is currently only implemented for the following platforms - Android, iOS, tvOS and desktop platforms.

So on Android you should be fine.

The `CertificateHandler` is by default [automatically disposed](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-disposeCertificateHandlerOnDispose.html) together with the `UnityWebRequest` so there is no more to do.