# Unity WebClient SSL Timeout

Tags: unity-game-engine, ssl, mono, webclient

I'm working on a Unity project that is reliyng on fetching data from a web API I set up on a public webserver. The server is currently set to self-signed ssl and requires the client to send certification to be able to read the data, if the client fails to send the cert the website returns with **"403 forbidden"**.

I've tested this in the browser and postman and everything works fine.
I've also tested the exact same function in a pure visual studio project and it worked like a charm.

However, when I try this function in Unity I am met with the WebException **"The request timed out
"**.

The way I'm currently doing it is via a WebClient, with an overrided method of WebRequest:

```
private void Connect()
{
    ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ignoreCertCallback;
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    using (var wc = new CertificateWebClient())
    {
        try
        {
            var responseBytes = wc.DownloadString(url);
            Debug.Log(responseBytes);
            Debug.Log(wc.ResponseHeaders);
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Override of WebRequest:

```
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
{   
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\temp\ClientCert.pfx", "password");

    request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (System.Object obj, X509Certificate X509certificate, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors errors)
    {
        return true;
    };
    Debug.Log(request.RequestUri);
    (request as HttpWebRequest).ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
    request.Timeout = 2000;
    return request;
}
```

Important to note is that I've tried the exact same functions inside of Unity with the "client.badssl.com" and their cert, and that also worked like a charm, returning the correct error codes when no cert is sent and everything and If I turn off client certification on my website, everything also works like charm...

From What I understand, It might be Mono that might be the problem as the certification is self-signed and not from a verified CA... But i've not been able to find a workaround... so any help would be great

Comment: You should rather use [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html) instead. Then you can follow [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55114077/7111561)

Comment: I can't use UnityWebRequest, since I need to actually send the client certificate and to my knowledge there is no way to do this with UnityWebRequest. 
I've allready gotten it to accept the actual server, if I turn off require client cert everything works fine... so the actual problem has to do something with the client certification

Answer (score 0):

What are your BG settings? I mean: is it on AWS? Express/NodeJS? WebGL? I am facing the same issue but when testing locally it works like a charm

I would suggest: to check if it is an infrastructure problem you might want to create a certificate for your domain (eg 'goodboy.mytest.io") that is certified from some free SSL providers (I can say LetsEncrypt just for testing) and launch a local server that's using that certificate, then go in your "hosts" file (depending on OS that you are currently running) and mock your localhost as "goodboy.mytest.io", so you can check if connecting to that domain everything goes fine without additional layers (usually placed between connection "bouncing" on web)

I'm following up this too