# Unity send data to database

Tags: database, unity-game-engine

I have a question about an issue with sending Data to my Database. I’m looking for a secure way to bring sensitive data such as ingame credits or Hwid's or Something like that in a database. So I thought I could use the unity’s WWWFORM with the post method but I have the fear that it is not secure because anyone could send something to the server using the Post method, or somebody could spam my Database server with requests and maybe hack my server. Maybe I thought of a secret key (token) to verify that it is my game that sends the data. However, if someone decompiles my game, then he can see the token and can also send data to my server. Do any of you know of a secure way to send data securely to the server without anyone being able to modify the data along the way or have access to the database?

Comment: `or somebody could spam my Database server with requests and maybe hack my server.` is something **always** can happen, is called DDOS attack and of course higly illegal ;) usually most of Gateways world wide will prevent that from happening .. additionally you can make your firewall do the same and entirely block an IP after X invalid requests ;)

Comment: `if someone decompiles my game` also is something always *can* happen and it is actually quite difficult to reliably encrypt data ... I guess using Post and HTTPS is the best you can get though. For the HTTPS you will need to [tell Unity to accept your SSL certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55112733/unitywebrequest-change-to-https) is fine since it is public anyway but this one the HTTPS/SSL protocol takes care of the encryption for you

Comment: @derHugo My Firewall already rejects a specific amount of requests. I know i could use an obfuscator and i already have an SSL certificate working, but if im using a post with unity, somebody could also do it and insert data like coins or something. Is there a way that my server only accepts the data from my game? Or is there a way that the server build from unity sends the data to my database?

Comment: Let users login wuth credentials and then assign an encryption key to each logged in user I guess

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not want to make a user login in my game. It can't be that the only possibility is to make a login.

Comment: so my question is who writes to your database? Where does someone "add coins"? This sounds like every user has an individual account / save file whatever anyway, or not?

Comment: I think the one with the coins may have been a bad example, here's another. Every time I start the game I would like to save the HWID of the player in my database. For this I post the HWID and the steamid to the website.

Comment: The website then saves this with a correct procedure and also assigns this correctly. However, so far anyone can post to this page. What I want to achieve now is that my server (website) only plays requests from my Unity and only accepts my game. I am still new in the network world, and do not know it so well. So is it possible to do something like this or how would I securely store things from client to server.