# Unity throw "unknown error" while connecting to https website

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ssl-certificate, unitywebrequest

Today suddenly UnityWebRequest started to throw out "unknown error" with the website which was fine during at least 1 year. Here is the code:

```
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://somedomain.com", form);
    StartCoroutine(WaitForRequestLoad(www));

    private IEnumerator WaitForRequestLoad(UnityWebRequest www)
    {
        using (www)
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.isHttpError)
            {
            }
            else if (www.isNetworkError)
            {
            // THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM OCCURS
            // www.error = "unknown error"
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

1. "http" version of the required domain works fine
2. "https" version of the required domain was working fine BEFORE today
3. some websites with "https" are called properly though others throw out "unknown error"

What can be the case? Couple of days ago, I cleaned the system with some special program and it could delete some locally required files. I did a search and it is advised to check locally stored certificates. I'm going to check the advise if it works.

Please advise

Comment: Maybe this helps you [UnityWebRequest change to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55112733/unitywebrequest-change-to-https/55114077#55114077) -> you need a proper Certificate handler ;)

Comment: Also note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is `c#`

Answer (score 0):

[Millions of Devices and Sites Could Stop Working on Thursday](https://thelatch.com.au/no-internet-root-expiry/).

> On 30 September, one of the largest providers of HTTPS certificates, Let’s Encrpyt, >is going to stop using an old root certificate — which is not something you get >after a hook up — and millions of devices and sites could be affected as they all >rely on the company for secure internet connection.

It's not Unity issue but the certificate provider itself.